# ASP .NET core mvc & Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm looking to integrate Microsoft Graph API into my ASP.NET core mvc solution. The thing is my app is hosted on Azure, I've know the appID aswell as the secretID, and the permissions are Ok on Azure.

I don't find any documentation on how to add the authentication to Graph at the same time as the already existing authentication to my website. I already tried to get access by getting an access token doing a POST request but it doesn't seem to be the better way to do it.

Some tips for me ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "integrate" but if you want to authenticate using facebook, did you follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)?

Comment: If you want to call facebook graph api within your application, I think there is a [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/windows-sdk) in c# with built in helpers/clients

Comment: @Nerevar Actually looking at it ty but I speak about Microsoft Graph
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview

Comment: Ah sorry I thought facebook graph My bad, mention it in your question it could be confusing

Comment: You're right, gonna edit it

Comment: There is also [this sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) (not official) If you can provide some code it could also help us understand where you are struggling. [This tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/06/21/registering-your-application-in-the-new-application-portal/) could also be a start.

Comment: Do you wan to let your app  access Microsoft Graph API? If it is, you can jsut add Microsoft Graph Pemissions for your sp.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't find any documentation on how to add the authentication to Graph at the same time as the already existing authentication to my website.

You could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect-aspnetcore) about using OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for AD v1.0 endpoint.

**Note:** You need to set the required permissions for your AAD app to access **Microsoft Graph** API on Azure Portal,then change the `GraphResourceId` under appsettings.json 
 to `https://graph.microsoft.com/`, and change the related request endpoint and parameters for accessing user profile under `UserProfileController.cs`.

Also, you could follow [Microsoft Graph Connect Sample for ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample) for Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.

Additionally, you could leverage the built-in [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and follow [Configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) without manually add authentication middleware in your code. Then you could retrieve tokens in your app code, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code).